# Can I use a nested uri for a single?

Tags: templating

I have a single. I want to set the uri to section/single. For example academy/sign-up. I have created a single and have a template file named sign-up.html in the right location (within academy folder). I get a 404 when requesting site.com/academy/sign-up. Removing academy from address works. Can I use the nested uri or do all singles need to sit at the top level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Single called *Sign Up* with a URI (section > settings) of `academy/sign-up` while keeping your current template `academy/sign-up.html`.

Comment: Your solution worked. I already had those settings. However I noticed the entry template field was incorrect. Thank you very much.